# velocity set $layout does not work

Tags: spring-mvc, velocity, template-engine

I am using Velocity with Spring MVC, every thing works very well in my template but set layout, I'm trying to define different layouts and use them in my templates but $layout is not doing anything for me. Am I using a wrong way to set a layout?

This is my layout file: (layout1.vm)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>$!page_title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>This is Layout #1</h1>
<div>
  $screen_content
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my template (hello.vm) is going to extend this layout:

```
#set( $layout = "layout1.vm" )

<ul>
#foreach ($name in $namelist)
  <li>${name}</li>
#end
</ul>
```

Both this files are located in the same directory, I'd really appreciate any help or suggestions about solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Spring's VelocityLayoutViewResolver (or something like that?) The default Velocity view resolver in Spring MVC doesn't have layout resolution support.

Comment: Yes that's right I am using Spring's VelocityLayoutViewResolver, thanks for your answer, is there a way to have layout management like this in Velocity?

Comment: The VelocityLayoutViewResolver should provide support for this, i think. You might want to ask about this on the spring forums. If you want to ditch Spring MVC, you can always just use the VelocityLayoutServlet from the VelocityTools project.